# Prevent Rails 3.1 (webrick?) from logging assets rendering

Tags: logging, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Every time I load a page, webrick pollutes its log with lots of assets rendering lines. I want it to render assets, but I don't want it to be logged, because it makes it really difficult to look into what really matters. How do I force it to stop doing that?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312448/how-to-disable-logging-of-asset-pipeline-sprockets-messages-in-rails-3-1 seems like the same issue

Comment: I wouldn't use webrick for a production application, anyways. Use thin , mongrel, or passenger. http://tenmiles.com/blog/2010/08/apache-passenger-and-other-server-alternatives-rails/

Answer (score 3):

There is an open ticket for [this https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2639](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2639), when it is closed and you have the lastest and greatest, in config/environments/development.rb add:

```
config.assets.logger = nil
```

Until the above issues is resolve, then this will work:

```
Rails.application.assets.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')
Rails::Rack::Logger.class_eval do
  def before_dispatch_with_quiet_assets(env)
    before_dispatch_without_quiet_assets(env) unless env['PATH_INFO'].index("/assets/") == 0
  end
  alias_method_chain :before_dispatch, :quiet_assets
end
```

Reference: [How to disable logging of asset pipeline (sprockets) messages in Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312448/how-to-disable-logging-of-asset-pipeline-sprockets-messages-in-rails-3-1)

Answer (score 2):

Add `gem 'quiet_assets', :group => :development`to your Gemfile. See https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets .