# How to ignore Rails 3 assets from log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets, asset-pipeline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable logging of asset pipeline (sprockets) messages in Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312448/how-to-disable-logging-of-asset-pipeline-sprockets-messages-in-rails-3-1)

is possible to hack logger in Rails3 to ignore requests for assets?

It is maddness to find something in log, when it is full of

```
Started GET "/assets/tiscali.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-09 19:59:45 +0200
Served asset /tiscali.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2639) is still open as of 02 Nov 2011.

A workaround solution is available in a similar question: [How to disable logging of asset pipeline (sprockets) messages in Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312448/how-to-disable-logging-of-asset-pipeline-sprockets-messages-in-rails-3-1)

Answer (score 12):

I think this could help https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets

> #### Deprecation
>
> As of `sprockets-rails` version `3.1.0`, used in current versions of rails, this gem is deprecated.
>
> The asset pipeline now supports a `quiet` option which suppresses output of asset requests:
>
> ```
> # config/environments/development.rb
>
> config.assets.quiet = true
> ```
>
> Relevant PR: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/355
>
> #### Info
>
> Quiet Assets turns off the Rails asset pipeline log. This means that it suppresses messages in your development log such as:
>
> ```
> Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-28 13:35:34 +0300
> Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (8ms)
> ```
>
> Support Ruby on Rails >= 3.1...
>
> #### Usage
>
> Simply installing Quiet Assets will suppress the log messages automatically. However, if you wish to temporarily re-enable the logging of the asset pipeline messages, place the following in your `config/application.rb` file:
>
> ```
> config.quiet_assets = false
> ```
>
> If you need to suppress output for other paths you can do so by specifying:
>
> ```
> config.quiet_assets_paths << '/silent/'
> ```

Answer (score 5):

How about an invert selection?

`tail -f log/development.log | grep -v asset`

This basically outputs everything except for the lines that contain the word "asset".

Comment: It is better than nothing, but it will replace lot of asset requests with empty space, so scrolling trought log is still pain in ass :)

Comment: If scrolling is the problem you can strip all the blank lines. tail -f log/development.log | grep -vE "(^$|asset)"

Comment: As a side note, I'm pretty sure someone with better *nix skills can come up with a better expression, but the point is that you can use tail -f to match anything you want.

Comment: Yes. "learn a little bit of grep" is better than screwing around with the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3.2:

create a initializer with the content:

```
Rails::Rack::Logger.class_eval do 
  def call_with_quiet_assets(env)
    previous_level = Rails.logger.level
    Rails.logger.level = Logger::ERROR if env['PATH_INFO'].index("/assets/") == 0 
    call_without_quiet_assets(env).tap do
      Rails.logger.level = previous_level
    end 
  end 
  alias_method_chain :call, :quiet_assets 
end
```

From here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2639