# Don't log asset requests in Rails 3.1 in development mode

Tags: logging, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable logging of asset pipeline (sprockets) messages in Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312448/how-to-disable-logging-of-asset-pipeline-sprockets-messages-in-rails-3-1)

Since enabling the asset pipeline my development log is full of things like:

```
Started GET "/assets/icons/close_32.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-19 11:05:39 +0100
Started GET "/assets/vendor/colorbox/controls.png" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-19 11:05:39 +0100
Served asset /icons/close_32.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
Served asset /vendor/colorbox/controls.png - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
```

This means that getting to the actual request in a log requires a lot of scrolling. I very rarely, if ever, care about these asset requests in my log so is there a way to disable logging for the asset requests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sometime in the future

```
config.assets.logger = nil
```

will be available, but for now try using **grep** to exclude everything related to assets.

Answer (score 6):

As Philip mentions

```
config.assets.logger = nil
```

It's still in Master so it's not implemented as of yet.

But in the meantime you can use

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

It still won't get you all the way but it will not output as much log messages.
Makes it a bit cleaner...