# Rails console log - how to customize what is printed in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, logging

When I run rails s it loads up and everything works.  When I browse to a page several lines of information are printed.  Mostly this is  the webpage getting the assets for the page.  I really don't need to see this and have it clutter my screen.  Is there a way to customize what gets printed in console?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For assets pipeline messages it seems that you can't (yet). See [How to disable logging of asset pipeline (sprockets) messages in Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312448/how-to-disable-logging-of-asset-pipeline-sprockets-messages-in-rails-3-1) and the [rails issue on Github](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2639)

You can do it in part by using these lines ([cre](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2639#issuecomment-2111450)[dits](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2639#issuecomment-2155188)) in your `development.rb` file

```
config.after_initialize do |app|
  app.assets.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')
end
```

Comment: I just tried it on rails 3.1 and with log-level :warn you don't get the asset pipeline logs

Comment: @spike yes, but with `:warn` loglevel you're suppressing also AR queries (which has :debug priority), this would be undesirable during development.

Answer (score 3):

For Rails 3.1, inside `config/environments/development.rb`, set the following to false:

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

Your logs will show you everything you want to see minus the assets.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the logging detail of the rails dev server by setting `config.log_level` in environments/development.rb. Setting it to :warn will get rid of most of the logging (you can always send your own messages with whatever log level you want so they still get printed).

```
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels