# Rails new listing creation form gets returned with a 304 http code instead of 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js, http-status-code-302

I have a rails form new.html.erb.
When I go to this link manually I get 200 OK on its get request.

But when I come to this page from another page,lets say my root page, I get 304-not modified http status code because of which I think some of my document.ready code is not getting executed properly.

Here is my new.html.erb file

```
<div class="ui padded page grid">

  <div class="ui eight wide column">

    <%=form_for @listing, :html=> { class:'ui form centered teal segment'},remote: true do |f|%>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%>
    <a class="ui teal ribbon label">
      New Listing</a>
      <h2 class="ui header">
        <i class="settings icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
          Create New Listing
          <div class="sub header">Manage your preferences</div>
        </div>
      </h2>

      <div class="required field">
        <label>Title</label>  
        <%=f.text_field :title,placeholder:'Title of the listing'%>
      </div>
      <div class="two fields">

        <div class="required field">
          <label>Pet</label>
          <%= f.select(:pet_type,options_for_select([['Dog',1,{class:'item'}],['Cat',2,{class:'item'}],['Bird',3,{class:'item'}]]),{prompt:'Pet'},class:'ui dropdown pet_type')%>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>Breed</label>
          <%= f.select(:breed_type,options_for_select(Breed.all.collect{|x| [x.name,x.id,class:'item']}),{prompt:'Breed'},class:'ui dropdown disabled breed_type')%>
        </div>



      </div>
      <div class="two fields">
        <div class="required field">
          <label>Gender</label>
          <%= f.select(:gender,options_for_select([['Male',1,{class:'item'}],['Female',2,{class:'item'}]]),{prompt:'Gender'},class:'ui dropdown gender')%>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>State</label>
          <select class="ui search dropdown">
            <option value="">State</option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
            <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
            <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="CA">California</option>
            <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
            <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
            <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
            <option value="FL">Florida</option>
            <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
            <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
            <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
            <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
            <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
            <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
            <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="ME">Maine</option>
            <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
            <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
            <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
            <option value="MT">Montana</option>
            <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
            <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="NY">New York</option>
            <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
            <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
            <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            <option value="UT">Utah</option>
            <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
            <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
            <option value="WA">Washington</option>
            <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
          </select>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="required field">
        <label>Tell everyone in short about your pet</label>
        <%=f.text_area :love_for_pets%>
      </div>
      <h4 class="ui dividing header">Additional Info</h4>
      <div class="two fields">
        <div class="required field">
          <label>Price</label>
          <div class="ui icon input">
            <%=f.text_field :price,placeholder:"Price"%>
            <i class="user icon"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>Phone Number</label>
          <div class="ui icon input">
            <%=f.text_field :phone_no,placeholder:"Phone_no"%>
            <i class="call icon"></i>
          </div>
        </div>



</div>



<div class="ui hidden divider"></div>
<div class="field">
  <div class="ui checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="hot-deals">
    <label>I agree to the <a href="#">Terms of Service</a>.</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="ui error message">
  <div class="header">We noticed some issues</div>
</div>
<%=f.submit 'Register',class:'ui button'%>
<div class="ui error message"></div>
<%end%>


</div>

<div class="ui eight wide column">

  <div class="ui teal segment dropzone" id="media-dropzone">
    <!--p class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span>
  </p-->
  <h2 class="ui center aligned icon header dz-message">
    <i class="upload icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      Upload File
      <div class="sub header">Drop your images here</div>
    </div>
  </h2>
</div>
</div>


</div>
```

Because of this my dropzone does not get initialized.Also the semantic ui dropdown fail to display.

I am assuming the reason behind this is that the document.ready is not getting hit, because of which the dom elements initialization is not happening.

/*listing.js.erb*/

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   

    /*Dropzone.options.mediaDropzone=false;*/
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    mediaDropzone=new Dropzone('div#media-dropzone',
    {
      url:"/listings/media",
      headers: 
      {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      autoProcessQueue:false,
      addRemoveLinks:true,
      parallelUploads: 10
    });
    mediaDropzone.on("success",function(file,responseText)
    {
      console.log(responseText.file_name.url);
      console.log(responseText);
    });


});
```

/*ListingController*/

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @breeds=Breed.all
        session[:listing].destroy
        @listing=Listing.new
    end

    def create
        @listing=Listing.new(listing_params)
        if @listing.save
            session[:listing]=@listing.id
            respond_to do |format|
                format.js
            end
        end
    end
    def media
        @listing=Listing.find(session[:listing])
        puts params
        @photo=Photo.new(file_name:params[:file],listing:@listing)
        if @photo.save!
            respond_to do |format|
                format.json{render :json=>@photo}

            end
        end

    end


    private
    def listing_params
        params.require(:listing).permit!
    end

end
```

/*routes.rb*/

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  root 'prime_petz#home'

  get 'prime_petz/home'

  get 'prime_petz/about'

  get 'prime_petz/contact'

  post 'listings/media'

  resources :listings
  resources :prime_petz
end
```

Comment: We miss **routes** and **controller**, the entire http status codes thing is handled there, we can't really help with this information only.

Comment: sorry, have added them now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 304 status code doesn't imply there is an error. It means that the asset files match with that of browsers. [In Rails 3.2.3 server I get error 304 Not Modified (5ms)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701559/in-rails-3-2-3-server-i-get-error-304-not-modified-5ms)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection

This looks like it's an issue with turbolinks.

Comment: It indeed was an issue with turbo links and got resolved when i removed the dependency on turblinks inside my application.js file.Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Turbolinks in Rails disables the `document.ready()` when navigating inside the app. Either you will have to disable it in the link option:

```
<%= link_to('foo', @foo, 'data-no-turbolink' => true) %>
```

Or you will have to install the turbolinks jquery gem:

https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks

Comment: Alright,I am trying your method now,let see if it works

Comment: Jorge de los santos, it's not working.Document.ready is not getting hit

Comment: The link method will only work if you are hitting directly the url. If you are coming through a controller you will need the turbolinks-jquery gem.

Comment: I tried your turbo links jquery gem only,It aint working

Comment: Is your script required in the page? Looks like listing should be plural in order to ensure the autoload in the asset pipeline...

Comment: is the name convention required for js files also

Comment: Convention is for everything in rails. If you are not using the naming convention then you will have to require the file inside the application.js or the view.