# Remove assets loading from error logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, logging

Is it possible to remove the loading of assets ( images for example ) from the logs? I would like to have just the view rendering in my log + with the activerecord stuff and no other things that distract.

Can you setup the logger to remove certain elements from the log such as asset loading? thx

Comment: This one is already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312448/how-to-disable-logging-of-asset-pipeline-sprockets-messages-in-rails-3-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add initializer quite_assets.rb with:

```
def is_windows?
    RUBY_PLATFORM['mswin32'] || RUBY_PLATFORM['mingw'] || RUBY_PLATFORM['cygwin']
end

destination = is_windows?? 'NUL' : '/dev/null'

Rails.application.assets.logger = Logger.new(destination)
Rails::Rack::Logger.class_eval do
  def call_with_quiet_assets(env)
    previous_level = Rails.logger.level
    Rails.logger.level = Logger::ERROR if env['PATH_INFO'].index("/assets/") == 0
    call_without_quiet_assets(env).tap do
      Rails.logger.level = previous_level
    end
  end
  alias_method_chain :call, :quiet_assets
end
```

Comment: Not home right now behing the dev machine, but definitly try this out!I let you know if this works thx! Where did you find this information?

Comment: This is working for me in two projects, find this info there https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2639 .

Comment: Very nice thanks, I flag it correct then since its the same as on github page you submitted and should work correctly, great finally remove those assets and the scrolling when debugging ! thx (y)

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody else stumbles upon this as I did here is a simpler solution. 
https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `development.rb` file.

```
config.assets.debug = false
```