# How do i turn off assets logging in development mode, in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I tried:

```
config.assets.logger = nil
```

And

```
config.assets.logger = false
```

Any clue how to get those pesky logs out?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312448/how-to-disable-logging-of-asset-pipeline-sprockets-messages-in-rails-3-1

Comment: Thanks jasonifunk, I actually didnt see this when i searched for it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

place this in config/initializers/quiet_assets.rb

```
if Rails.env.development?
  Rails.application.assets.logger = Logger.new('/dev/null')
  Rails::Rack::Logger.class_eval do
    def call_with_quiet_assets(env)
      previous_level = Rails.logger.level
      Rails.logger.level = Logger::ERROR if env['PATH_INFO'] =~ %r{^/assets/}
      call_without_quiet_assets(env)
    ensure
      Rails.logger.level = previous_level
    end
    alias_method_chain :call, :quiet_assets
  end
end
```

its a fairly common solution to this problem

also can just use a gem

```
gem 'quiet_assets', :group => :development
```

Comment: +1 for the gem; it's become standard in all my apps.

Comment: why `quiet_assets` instad of `call_with_quiet_assets`?