# Rails Server-- clearing unwanted logs in rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when ever I am using my app in local machine I have to on the server

```
    $rails server
```

each time I do something in my app in the browser all the assets, jquery logs appear in the terminal like

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery.ui.core.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-11 12:38:44 +0530
....
.....
```

and so on like this .
If i dont want to see them in my logs each time what should I do?

Am new to Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible this [How to disable logging of asset pipeline (sprockets) messages in Rails 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312448/how-to-disable-logging-of-asset-pipeline-sprockets-messages-in-rails-3-1) is the answer your question.

Briefly, you can use this gem: https://github.com/evrone/quiet_assets

Comment: Your answer helped me.Now I am not getting the asset logs.Thank you!